# problem installing plugin in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi 
 I am having ruby 1.9.1 version . 
I am trying to install acts_as_taggable_redux plugin for tagging. 
When i do the following command :

`ruby script/plugin install https://github.com/geemus/acts_as_taggable_redux.git`

Its says

> already installed: acts_as_taggable_redux (https://github.com/geemus/acts_as_tag
>   gable_redux).  pass --force to reinstall

when i try doing ruby script/plugin list . Nothings returns..

Where is the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: to install the plugin from github, git has to be present.. after installing it , worked fine ..oops..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ruby script/plugin source https://github.com/geemus/acts_as_tag gable_redux`

and then use `ruby script/plugin install https://github.com/geemus/acts_as_tag gable_redux --force`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's already installed (which you noticed), are you sure you don't have it already? If you don't, you can pass --force to reinstall. Also, which rails are you using?